Curl post request with different body in parallel
Is it possible to send multiple POST request in parallel, but with different body?
Want to check race condition
I found out how to multiple POST request in parallel:

curl -i --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 3 -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"x":100}' --config websites.txt


websites.txt file:

url = "website1.com"
url = "website2.com"
url = "website3.com"


but haven't found out how to do it when body of the requests are different
any ideas?

If you're on Unix, you could make 3 separate curl commands and append an & to run them in the background.
